# How to implement TensorBoard from inside Pytorch module class

Tags: pytorch

I have the following pytroch nn module subclass. How can I get the benefit of tensorboard visualization as I'm new to the subject.

```
from torch import nn
```

class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self, optimizer):
    super().__init__()   
    self.optimizer = optimizer

    # Initialize Weights and Bias
    self.weights = nn.Parameter(
        torch.randn(1, 13, dtype=torch.float),
        requires_grad=True) 
    self.bias = nn.Parameter(
        torch.randn(1, 13, dtype=torch.float),
        requires_grad=True
        )

def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return (self.weights * x + self.bias).sum(axis=1)

def trainModel(
        self,
        epochs: int,
        X_train: torch.Tensor,
        X_test: torch.Tensor,
        y_train: torch.Tensor,
        y_test: torch.Tensor,
        lr: float
        ):

    torch.manual_seed(42)
   
    self.train_loss_values = []
    self.test_loss_values = []

    loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()

    if self.optimizer == 'SGD':
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(
            params=self.parameters(),
            lr=lr
            )
    elif self.optimizer == 'Adam':
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
            params=self.parameters(),
            lr=lr
            )
```

Please advise.

B. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it as follows:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
%load_ext tensorboard
from torch import nn


from torch import nn

class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):

'''
Torch Module class.
Initializes weight randomly and gets trained via train method.
'''
def __init__(self, optimizer):
    super().__init__()   #The super call delegates the function call to the parent class, which is nn.
    self.optimizer = optimizer

    # Initialize Weights and Bias
    self.weights = nn.Parameter(
        torch.randn(1, len(X_train[1]), dtype=torch.float),
        requires_grad=True) #main use case is to tell autograd to begin recording operations on a Tensor tensor .
                            #autograd is PyTorch’s automatic differentiation engine that powers neural network training.
    self.bias = nn.Parameter(
        torch.randn(1, len(X_train[1]), dtype=torch.float),
        requires_grad=True
        )
'''
Now, our goal is to optimize these weights via backpropagation —
for that we need to setup our linear layer, consisting of the regression formula:
'''
def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return (self.weights * x + self.bias).sum(axis=1)

'''
The trainModel method will help us perform backpropagation and weight adjustment:
'''
def trainModel(
        self,
        epochs: int,
        X_train: torch.Tensor,
        X_test: torch.Tensor,
        y_train: torch.Tensor,
        y_test: torch.Tensor,
        lr: float
        ):
    '''
    Trains linear model using pytorch.
    Evaluates the model against test set for every epoch.
    '''
    torch.manual_seed(42)
    # Create empty loss lists to track values
    self.train_loss_values = []
    self.test_loss_values = []

    loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()

    if self.optimizer == 'SGD':
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(
            params=self.parameters(),
            lr=lr
            )
    elif self.optimizer == 'Adam':
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
            params=self.parameters(),
            lr=lr
            )
for epoch in range(epochs):
        self.train()
        y_pred = self(X_train)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Set the model in evaluation mode
        self.eval()
        with torch.inference_mode():
            self.evaluate(X_test, y_test, epoch, loss_fn, loss, epochs)

def evaluate(self, X_test, y_test, epoch_nb, loss_fn, train_loss, epochs):
    '''
    Evaluates current epoch performance on the test set.
    '''
    writer = SummaryWriter('runs/working_directory')
    test_pred = self(X_test)
    test_loss = loss_fn(test_pred, y_test.type(torch.float))
    if epoch_nb % 10 == 0:
        self.train_loss_values.append(train_loss.detach().numpy())
        self.test_loss_values.append(test_loss.detach().numpy())
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch_nb} - MAE Train Loss: {train_loss} - MAE Test Loss: {test_loss} ")
        #writer.add_scalar("train_loss x epoch", train_loss)
        writer.add_scalar("test_loss x epoch", test_loss, epoch_nb)
    if epoch_nb >= epochs:
        writer.close()

# train a model using Adam optimizer and 0.001 learning rate for 500 epochs:
adam_model = LinearRegressionModel('Adam')
adam_model.trainModel(500, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, 0.001)

tensorboard  --logdir=runs`enter code here`
```